# Custom DXA main region

Tags: dxa

On a DXA 1.6 .NET based website I want to remove the core module and use my own module for all models and views. How can I tell DXA to use my custom "Main" region view instead of the OOTB `Core:Region:Main` view?

Update: 
I managed to create a custom module in the Content Manager; and in the webapp our custom models, and entity, region, page and include views. The last piece of the puzzle is the Main region. I think the Main region does not have a component template, page template or template meta data associated so I wonder how to write the Main region to my custom region view.

Comment: "I think the Main region does not have a CT associated" -- it's the other way around; you always have a CT, but if the CT doesn't specify a Region (View) name (either in metadata or in its title), then the Entity is put in a Region called "Main" (using the `Core:Main` View).  If you don't want that to happen, just ensure you specify a Region View name on your CTs.

Comment: Thanks Rick, it is indeed the other way around. DXA chooses the defaults if you do not specify a region view in the CT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using only your own models and views, then presumably you are also creating your own schemas, PTs and CTs.

I guess you have two approaches:

1. Delete all the existing Core Area views, and replace them with your own. DXA uses core as the default area if it doesn't get one specified in the CT/PT metadata
2. Create a new Area for your views, and configure your CT and PT metadata to ensure that they point to the new area. For the CTs in the main area just set `MyModule:Main` in the `Region View Name` property on the CT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Will. I did just that: all my CTs and Pats are wired to my custom module/area. The missing piece is the Main region view. I have added some info to the question to clarify.

Comment: You can specify the region (with area/module prefix in the CT metadata)

Comment: Approach 2 is the clean way to do this and it works for me. What I overlooked when asking this question is that you can simply set `MyModule:Main` for the `Region View Name` property on the component template.